# The command to move file * .pas to file * .exe in fpc.exe

Tags: pascal

I have a fpc.exe executable file that is supposed to transfer the * .pas file to * .exe file but when i click on it to write command it shows help, i write command but it does not work. The command is as follows (I learned from this link :https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse10.html)
  fpc [options] prog.pp

I wrote on the command box
fpc C: \ Hello.pas prog.pp
I put the Hello.pas file in drive C
What should I do in this case

Thank you so much I tried it another way, is to cmd and then type the command
fpc D: \ Hello
And this is my video
https://youtu.be/MsOfohAZjqg
I finally did it. Thank you.

Comment: We can't see your screen.  What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: Well wait for me

Comment: đây là video của tôi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EvVXXBTNy0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Sorry, when I said "We can't see your screen", I didn't mean you should make a video, just that we need the problem to be explained **in words** - I'm afraid "it does not work" is not a useful problem description.

Comment: In general I want to create a run button in visual basic to convert the * .pas file to * .exe

Comment: Cảm ơn bạn rất nhiều Tôi đã thử nó một cách khác, là để cmd và sau đó gõ lệnh fpc D: \ Hello Và đây là đoạn video của tôi https: / / yeoutu.be/MsOfohAZjqg cuối cùng tôi đã làm nó. Cảm ơn bạn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote on the command box
>   fpc C: \ Hello.pas prog.pp

There are several things wrong with this:

1. You should leave out the "prog.pp".  The example in the link is using that as an example of the name of the source file to compile.  Yours is Hello.Pas.
2. There should be no spaces in the file name of the source file.
3. Do you have write permission to the root directory of your C: drive?  If not, you should move your source file(s) to a directory where you do.

So, you need something like this

fpc C:\mypascal\Hello.Pas

This will only work, btw, if `fpc` is on your OS Path.  If it isn't, then either add add it to the Path, or include the full path to `fpc.exe` in your compile command.

Btw, when you said

> I have a fpc.exe executable file that is supposed to transfer the * .pas file to * .exe file

actually that is not quite right.  You don't have the executable file, the executable file is what you are trying to create from the Hello.Pas file by compiling it using `fpc`.

> when I click on the fpc file, it immediately prompts me to use and tells me to hit enter

I assume you mean that this happens when you click `fpc.exe` in an Explorer window.  I'm afraid there is no easy way to avoid this  - the same thing happens if you just type

C:>fpc

in a command window.   It is just listing the various compiler options, etc, that you could specify.  The way you avoid that in a command window is to specify the name of the source file you want to compile.  Unfortunately, there isn't a simple way of specifying the source file when you click `fpc`.  For Explorer, it is easiest to write a batch file which prompts you for the source file name and then invokes `fpc` to compile it.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for answering the question.
Another problem is that when I click on the fpc file, it immediately prompts me to use and tells me to hit enter so I can not enter the command line fpc C: \ Hello.pas.

Comment: a)  When you say " Another problem is that when I click on the fpc **file**"?  Which "fpc" file do you mean, `fpc.exe` or what?  b) How are you clicking it, in an Explorer window, clicking its desktop icon or what?

Comment: Yes, it's fpc.exe, clicked by clicking in explorer

Comment: Cảm ơn bạn rất nhiều Tôi đã thử nó một cách khác, là để cmd và sau đó gõ lệnh fpc D: \ Hello Và đây là đoạn video của tôi https: / / yeoutu.be/MsOfohAZjqg cuối cùng tôi đã làm nó. Cảm ơn bạn.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the `prog.pp` in your command line and just enter 
`fpc C:\Hello.pas` (if the file really is located in the root of C:).
If FPC does not find errors, you should have a file `C:\Hello.exe`.

Comment: Hi
Thank you for answering the question.
Another problem is that when I click on the fpc file, it immediately prompts me to use and tells me to hit enter so I can not enter the command line fpc C: \ Hello.pas.

Comment: Clicking on fpc.exe just executes it **without parameters** i.e. it displays the help. Depending on your system/installation you should click on the pas file (maybe the FPC IDE or Lazarus opens the file). **You can right-click on the pas, choose `open with` and search/select fpc.exe**

Comment: Cảm ơn bạn rất nhiều Tôi đã thử nó một cách khác, là để cmd và sau đó gõ lệnh fpc D: \ Hello Và đây là đoạn video của tôi https: / / yeoutu.be/MsOfohAZjqg cuối cùng tôi đã làm nó. Cảm ơn bạn.